# How to use ExcludeConstraint in SQLAlchemy with Flask

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to **rewrite** following SQL statement to **FLASK** with **SQLAlchemy**

```
CREATE TABLE test (id int, intrange int4range, EXCLUDE USING GIST (intrange WITH &&));
```

The ultimate goal is to insert INT from and to (e.g. [10, 20]) and if someone wants to
INSERT another range, it should never overlap.

```
valid:    [21, 40]
invalid:  [5, 7]
```

My Python Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ExcludeConstraint
from sqlalchemy_utils import IntRangeType

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/bbb.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class TestModel(db.Model):
    """Network table"""

    __tablename__ = 'test'
    # CREATE TABLE test (id int, intrange int4range, EXCLUDE USING GIST (intrange WITH &&));
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    intrange = db.Column(IntRangeType,
                          ExcludeConstraint(
                              ("intrange", "&&"),
                              name="unique_intrange_constraint",
                              using="gist",
                          ),
                          index=True, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using wrong database, cause it is supported just for PostgreSQL

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ExcludeConstraint
from sqlalchemy_utils import IntRangeType

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(
    "postgres",
    "password",
    "127.0.0.1",
    5432,
    "postgres")
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class TestModel(db.Model):
    """Network table"""
    """CREATE TABLE test (id int, intrange int4range, EXCLUDE USING GIST (intrange WITH &&));"""

    __tablename__ = 'test'
    __table_args__ = (

        ExcludeConstraint(('intrange', '&&')),
    )

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    intrange = db.Column(
        IntRangeType,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
```

Then when inserting correct values (valid ranges)

```
postgres=# select * from test;
 id | intrange 
----+----------
  1 | [42,45)
  2 | [47,60)
(2 rows)
```

Now, insert invalid range

```
postgres=# INSERT INTO test VALUES (3, '(50,53)');
ERROR:  conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "test_intrange_excl"
DETAIL:  Key (intrange)=([51,53)) conflicts with existing key (intrange)=([47,60)).
```